# How to load a JSON config file on start up automatically using Jackson in Java Springboot

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

I have these files:

```
@Component
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:prop.json")
public class Prop {
    String hello;
    String bye;
   ...

   // Getters and Setters and toString
}
```

My Application

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = { Prop.class})
public class TestApp {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(TestApp.class, args);
}
```

}

My prop.json configuration file

```
{
  "hello": "test1",
  "bye": "test2"
}
```

My test class:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(
        classes = Prop.class)
class PropTest {

    @Autowired
    private Prop jsonProperties;

    @Test
    public void testone() {
        System.out.println(jsonProperties.toString());
    }
}
```

My test is printing out : `Prop{hello='null', bye='null'}`

It works fine when I use an ObjectMapper and retrieve it the old fashion way, but shouldn't Springboot be able to load configs like this? What am I missing?

Comment: Does annotating your `Prop` class with [`@ConfigurationProperties`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationProperties.html) solve the problem?

Comment: It needs a prefix. What would that be for json

Comment: I'm not sure, but I would imagine it's the (dot-separated?) path to the JSON Object whose fields you want to bind. In the file you shared, the fields are at the top level. So maybe the prefix is an empty string (`""`)?

Comment: It requires a nonempty string I tried something like {"test": { "hello": "test1", "bye":"test2"}} and putting test but no luck. But after autowiring an Environment object in and looking through it in debug mode, it is one of the propertySources, so springboot is scanning it, just not autowiring to my Prop variable for some reason